# Jersey client javax.ws.rs.client.Client not found

Tags: java, jersey, client

I have a jersey client. I have the following imports in the client class

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

When I compile the application I get

```
./src/com/uciext/ws/class2/client/StudentClient.java:3: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
                         ^
```

How can I fix the issue

EDITED:

```
This is the error trace

./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:4: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
                         ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:5: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
                         ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:6: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
                         ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:7: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
                         ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:8: error: package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
                         ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:9: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
                       ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:10: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
                       ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
         Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
         ^
  symbol:   class Client
  location: class InventoryClient
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
         Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                         ^
  symbol:   variable ClientBuilder
  location: class InventoryClient
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
         WebTarget myResource = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/inventory/rest/catalog");
         ^
  symbol:   class WebTarget
  location: class InventoryClient
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:17: error: package Invocation does not exist
         Invocation.Builder builder = myResource.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                   ^
./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/InventoryClient.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
         Invocation.Builder builder = myResource.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable MediaType
  location: class InventoryClient
12 errors
```

This is the c.sh. I use jersey 2.2.7. I downloaded jersey 2.2.7 and copied it in my lib folder. Can I have the wrong version of jar.

```
JAXB_PATH=./lib/jaxb-ri-2.2.7/lib
JAXB_LIB=$JAXB_PATH/jaxb-api.jar:$JAXB_PATH/jaxb-core.jar:$JAXB_PATH/jaxb-impl.jar:$JAXB_PATH/jaxb-jxc.jar:$JAXB_PATH/jaxb-xjc.jar
JAXRS_PATH=./lib/jaxrs-ri/lib
JAXRS_API=./lib/jaxrs-ri/api
JAXRS_LIB=$JAXRS_PATH/jersey-server.jar:$JAXRS_PATH/jersey-common.jar:$JAXRS_PATH/jersey-container-servlet.jar:$JAXRS_PATH/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:$JAXRS_API/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./lib/jaxrs-ri/api
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./lib/jaxb-ri-2.2.7/lib
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./lib/jaxrs-ri/lib
javac -classpath $JAXB_LIB:$JAXRS_LIB:. -d classes ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/util/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/backend/model/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/backend/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/backend/impl/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/service/model/catalog/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/service/model/order/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/service/model/orderconfirm/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/service/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/service/impl/*.java
javac -classpath $JAXB_LIB:$JAXRS_LIB:. -d classes ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/model/catalog/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/model/order/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/model/orderconfirm/*.java ./src/com/uciext/ws/hw2/client/*.java
```

Comment: What jars d you currently have? Are you not using an IDE? Why are you only catching this error when you compile?

Answer (score -1):

Have you included the dependencies to get the implementation of this package?
If you are using maven [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client) post give the details.
For library version, download libraries from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.25.1/jaxrs-ri-2.25.1.zip) and follow the following [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm) for adding the required jars. Although the Client class is available in jaxrs-ri\api jar.

Comment: I am using jar. What jar do I jar to include in lib folder?

Comment: I work without IDE, in the folder lib of my project I copied the folde rjaxb-ri-2.2.7
jaxrs-ri

Comment: What is your build environment? Are you using plain javac?

Comment: I compile with a sh. Yes I use a plain javac

Comment: You need to add these jars in your class path. You can put path till your jar in your bashrc export something like this CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/libs/jaxrs-ri/api

Answer (score -1):

You want to grab [this zip file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.30/jaxrs-ri-2.30.zip) and make sure the `jaxrs-ri/api/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar` is in your classpath.